# Ruby on Rails: Is there a way to tell what fields failed validation in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm attempting to create an XML builder file that tells a user to know exactly what fields failed validation in the output. I also want to display their input back to them, so that requires me figuring out which fields failed validation. Meaning if someone fails on creating a new user resource, I want to display XML that's meaningful (Besides a meaningful HTTP status number) such as:

```
<errors>
    <user>
        <email>bad@email: Invalid email format</email>
    </user>
<errors>
```

The above is tough to do in an XML builder file without knowing what field failed. And if I just iterate over error messages, I won't know how to prob my @user object to get the value that the user supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ActiveRecord::Errors#on`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Errors.html#M002206)

```
company = Company.create(:address => '123 First St.')
company.errors.on(:name)      # => ["is too short (minimum is 5 characters)", "can't be blank"]
company.errors.on(:email)     # => "can't be blank"
company.errors.on(:address)   # => nil
```

Or you can use [`ActiveRecord::Errors#each`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Errors.html#M002209) to get all attributes with errors

```
company = Company.create(:address => '123 First St.')
company.errors.each{|attr,msg| puts "#{attr} - #{msg}" }
# => name - is too short (minimum is 5 characters)
#    name - can't be blank
#    address - can't be blank
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the [API docs](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Errors.html):

```
company.errors.each{|attr,msg| puts "#{attr} - #{msg}" } # =>
  name - is too short (minimum is 5 characters)
  name - can't be blank
  address - can't be blank
```

Isn't this what you're looking for: the `attr` variable will be the field name.